# Android SIP stack: NullPointerException on register

Tags: android, sip

I've been writing code on a HTC Desire Z running 2.3.3 and it works fine - now I've come to test it on another device (Nexus One running 2.3.4), and it crashes. Here's the code:

```
if (me == null || sipManager == null || listener == null){
    Log.e("OH","NO");
}

sipManager.register(me, 30, listener);
```

None of the things I pass to sipManager.register are null (the log is never called), but here's my stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.myapp.Service: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1955)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.net.sip.SipManager.register(SipManager.java:474)
    at com.myapp.Service.onCreate(Service.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1945)
    ... 10 more
```

Looking at the Android source doesn't seem to reveal anything obvious either - everything I'm passing to it is valid on another device.

Both devices are running 2.3+ and both have the SIP stack enabled:

```
if (SipManager.isVoipSupported(this) && SipManager.isApiSupported(this)){
```

EDIT:

Here's a full activity which replicates the issue:

```
public class SIPTest extends Activity {

    public SipManager sipManager = null;
    SipProfile me = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        if (SipManager.isVoipSupported(this) && SipManager.isApiSupported(this)){
            // SIP is supported, let's go!
            Log.e("SIP", "SUPPORTED");
            sipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);


            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";
            String domain = "example.org";

            try {
                SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
                builder.setPassword(password);
                builder.setDisplayName(username);
                builder.setProfileName(username + "@" + domain);
                me = builder.build();

                sipManager.register(me, 30, new SipRegistrationListener() {
                        public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                            Log.e("SIP","Registering with SIP Server...");
                        }

                        public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                            Log.e("SIP","Ready!");
                        }

                        public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                String errorMessage) {
                            Log.e("SIP","Registration failed. " + errorMessage + " ("+errorCode+") - " + localProfileUri);
                        }
                    });
            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                Log.e("SIP","Connection Error.");
            } catch (SipException se) {
                Log.e("SIP","Connection error.");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen other people mention that it crashes on the N1 if instantiated inside a Service as well, apparently it works fine in an Activity.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly that doesn't appear to be the case - I edited my answer with some sample code. You should get an authentication error if it works correctly (since username:password@example.org isn't a valid SIP account).

Comment: You've definitely got all the AndroidManifest permissions in place? INTERNET and USE_SIP

Comment: Yup. I can email you a full project? :)

Comment: Do you have an empty string constructor for the service which super against a string?

Comment: @Carl - I'm not really sure what that means, to be honest. Have a look at the full Activity at the bottom of my question - that's all of the code.

Comment: FWIW, I've also restored the Nexus One back to factory settings too. Still nothing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shall just place sipManager.open(me); before sipManager.register() is executed as new sip session needs to be created.

take care!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in the android code.

You can see from the logs that Sipsession tries to call `OnRegisteredDone` but fails because of a null pointer

I noticed alot of null pointer from the sipsession, this is what is causing registration issues in the sipmanager

> 04-26 00:05:20.946: D/Dialapp(18910): ActivitySIPCallScreen:SipRegistrationListener\onRegisteringDone sip:105@192.168.1.1
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: D/Dialapp(18910): ActivitySIPCallScreen:updateStatus\String\Registered sip:105@192.168.1.1
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937): onRegistrationDone()
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937):     at android.net.sip.ISipSessionListener$Stub$Proxy.onRegistrationDone(ISipSessionListener.java:416)
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937):     at com.android.server.sip.SipSessionListenerProxy$10.run(SipSessionListenerProxy.java:173)
>   04-26 00:05:20.946: W/SipSession(1937):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)

Answer (score 0):

There have been similar issues relating to nexus one and SIP reported on the issues list:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17078&q=SIP%20register&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

I'd suggest stepping through a debug at that point on to monitor the params which set up the ISipSession. It might be that some of them are being set up incorrectly because of a system config.

**Code for others to explore**

Here is the line in question for others looking at the problem:
http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/voip/java/android/net/sip/SipManager.java&q=package:android.git%20SipManager.java&l=474